# How to undefine one role in a relation in Grakn

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I have a relation in Grakn with several roles. I want to undefine one of those roles. Let's say I have this relation:

```
define
drive sub relation, 
relates driven, 
relates driving;
```

If I run this command:

```
undefine drive sub relation, relates driven;
```

I get the error below:

```
Error: UNKNOWN: Type [drive] cannot be deleted as it still has incoming edges. Please check server logs for the stack trace.
All uncommitted data is cleared
```

How can I undefine one of these two roles?

Answer (score 0):

In Grakn 1.8, you need to separately undefine the roles in order to undefine a relation:

```
undefine
drive relates driven;
drive relates driving;
drive sub relation;
```

If anything `plays` `driven` or `driving`, you will need to undefine that too, e.g:

```
undefine person plays driven;
```